# Asp.Net MVC 4, LocalDB and separated service layer project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm built a forms authentication (actually I'm using the new single page application) website using Asp.net MVC 4.0 with LocalDB. I want to create a separated class lib project for service layer which accesses database. And I need to integrate the default Account/authentication tables with my own tables.

**Question:**

1. Should I put the Sql server LocalDB files under the service project folder?
2. If the answer is not for (1), how can the service project access the LocalDB files under the MVC project?
3. Do I need to modify the system generated code for Account login if I put the LocalDB file under service project. How about let the authentication code access the database via the service layer instead of the default DBContext?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is very common and the main control and point of understanding is IIS and security there.
It really is worth taking a look at MSDN IIS site to feel confident about this topic.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

1) It doesnt matter where SQL server DB is located.  Where the SQL server instance is , does play a role.  If it is in the same domain/AD , then using Windows integrated security to log in to the DB works well.
2) If the userid that connects to SQL is a valid user on the DB instance and has the necessary permissions for the underlying DB, then you can access the data.

3) What is this code ?

There are a number of questions that need to be answered/considered.

a) are you using FORMS logon or Windows Integrated logon in IIS.
b) Do you want to use a service user to access the DB, or have each user allocated the in the Db.
c) What is is your security model for your application.

See also http://leastprivilege.com/category/net-security/   Dominick Baier security blog.

**As a sample solution, (not the only one).**

- you can set the website in IIS to use FORMS authentication
- Set the application pool used by the website in in IIS to use a specific Service user. You type the userid and password into IIS app pool. You must first create this user on the domain.   Allocate it  as little rights as possible.
- Add this service user to SQL server and give it sufficient permissions in the DB that should be accessed. (2 steps) So the service user can access the DB but do little else.

So this leaves you with **System.Environment.UserName**  as the System user you set in your app pool behind the website.
Your application security is then managed as you see fit.
Claims principal once you get to .net 4.5 is a "new way".
But you keep as simple as required here.
**Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name**  would contain the name of your forms based user.

good luck...

[image]